# z3: do the orders of constraints being asserted affect the orders they are evaluated?

Tags: z3, smt, z3py

My z3py code is doing inference and experiencing some performance (latency) issues. Currently I am trying to come up with some heuristics to prune the search space to hopefully boost the speed of inference.

My question is: do the orders of constraints being asserted affect the orders they are evaluated? In other words, if a constraint can significantly reduce the search space, should I assert it first so that, after being evaluated, many impossible solutions will be rule out at an early stage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ordering of assertions can make a difference for the heuristics later, but there is no pre-defined order that would perform the "best". Asserting particular constraints earlier does, in general, not mean that they will be solved first.

Comment: Is there a way to tell z3 to solve particular constraints first?

Comment: No. You can add `(check-sat)` or call `check` at any point and it will solve the constraints currently in scope. Note that that's a satisfiability check though, i.e. the result of that check may be completely useless (and ignored) in later checks. Some heuristic state is kept between multiple calls, but that is entirely internal to the solver.